# Jmeter parametrize WebSocket variable

Tags: url, jmeter

I doing test backend application (also Java and Node JS, communication: WebSocket in NodeJs part and http in Java part) in JMeter
I must parametrize url, to switch between development url, production and prepod

I did it by CSV file. I created folder CSV, in folder where I have Jmeter 5.0. I prepare 3 csv file

1.development are:

```
protocol,   host
http,   10.219.227.66
```

2.prepod

```
protocol,   host        
https,  prepod.myprepod.io
```

3.production

```
protocol,   host        
https,  production.myproduction.io
```

I set this that:

CSV Data Set Config

```
Filename ${_P()/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/libexec/CSV/development,development}.csv
variable Names ; protocol,host
```

WebSocket Open Connection
    Server name or IP ${host}

```
Switch Controller
Switch Value ${protocol}
HTTP Request Default - server name or ip ${host}, protocol http ${protocol}
```

User defined variables

```
name        value
protocol .  ${_P(protocol,)}
host .      ${_P(host,)}
```

Questions are:

1. What is wrong in my set this? what and how i must improve?
2. I project test save in desktop,but Jmeter 5.0 i have in others places in my computer - in users is folder jmeter 5 - if this could be a problem?
3. Does anyone know why it does not work for me and how to fix it?.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is wrong

1. Given you defined `protocol` and  `host` variables in the CSV file you don't need to declare them in the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), just leave the field blank

   > JMeter supports CSV files which have a header line defining the column names. To enable this, leave the "Variable Names" field empty. The correct delimiter must be provided.
2. Don't use full paths to CSV files as most probably it will make running tests on other machines, in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) or in [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server impossible.

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

   so go for something like `${__P(environment,development)}.csv`
3. Double check that `protocol` and `host` variables have expected values using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

   [image: JMeter debug sampler view results tree listener]

   If you don't see them - check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries, most probably JMeter cannot find .csv file and read variables from it. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details.
4. I fail to see any [WebSocket URL schema (`ws` or `wss`)](https://hpbn.co/websocket/#ws-and-wss-url-schemes) in your CSV files so I doubt your WebSocket Open Connection Server will ever be successfully executed.